How should I use this ladder to access my roof?
This is a continuation of my previous question.
So, I went to my local home improvement store and bought some gear - the roof hooks (see previous question) and another, longer ladder.
The ladder in particular is this one:

That was the only ladder that was both long enough (at least 6m), and could fit (barely) in my car.
Then I went back and tried to get on the roof... but still failed. So now I have more questions.
First - is this the right ladder after all? Note the hooks on the bottoms that the ladder pieces use to hold together when extended. They're open on the bottom. This works nicely when the ladder is standing on the ground, but not so much when it's hanging from the hooks. I tried securing them together with some rope, which I think might have worked, although it was a bit dubious. However I didn't really get to use it because of the second problem.
Second - how do I use it anyway? At first I tried using my smaller ladder to get to the edge of the roof and then roll the big ladder up the roof, as demonstrated by this fabulous schematic:

By mustering all my force I could get the big ladder where it needed to be... but I couldn't flip it over. I needed my left hand to hold on to the smaller ladder, and the big ladder was too heavy to flip it with just one of my hands. If I was to let go of the small ladder, the weight of the big one would topple me over backwards.
Then I tried the opposite - I attached the hook to the small ladder and tried to use the big ladder to get halfway. Like this:

This time I couldn't even get halfway up between the ground and the roof edge. The big ladder started to sag dangerously. It's really not made for such a shallow angle.
Then it started raining and I had to abandon my efforts for the day.
I'm going back tomorrow and... any tips?

A safety harness and a long rope that can be anchored to something(big tree) on the other side.  And a second person.

@crip659 A second person I can get. Note that I don't want to stand on the roof directly - I don't  think the roof "tiles"/"shingles"/"whatever they're called" will support my weight. That's why I want a ladder - to distribute my weight and make climbing up and down easier. But getting that ladder up there is currently my biggest challenge.

The safety harness and rope is to hold you so you can use both hands.  The second person is to put the ladder back in position when you knock it down and hanging in the harness.

Could you get a couple lengths of PVC pipe connected to create a long "poker" that you can use from the other side of the building to flip the ladder?

Shingles can be stepped upon, unless the roof has rotted out beneath them. If you want to do that, you want a ladder long enough to extend over the roof edge by several feet, so you can step from ladder onto roof and back without awkward twisting and while having something to hold onto.
Lifting a ladder takes strength and leverage. I really wouldn't suggest doing it one-handed, I'm afraid. And having someone else to steady the ladder as you climb helps a lot.
Sometimes the right answer is scaffolding or a lift rather than a ladder.

Thanks for the edit. Sigh. Getting sloppy in my dotage.

I think that's the problem—OP isn't sanguine about the solidness of the roof.  The ladder is to spread the load.


Is this the right ladder after all?

No. I've not seen ladders like this and it's not practical in any way, since you cannot adjust the angle easily. You need an extension ladder, not this extension/A-frame combo you have currently. You probably spent more on this than the mere extension would run you.
I would highly recommend buying a fiberglass extension ladder (like this one) instead of a pure aluminum. They support more weight, and tend to have better bulk to limit sliding (mine has a rubber guard on top for use against siding)

Ahh, maybe you have a different link? That one seems to be blocked in my country. But also - my ladder can be used similarly to an extension ladder (as in - all 3 segments hooked on each other in a straight line). What worries me is that the hooks for my ladder only work in one way - they prevent the ladder from collapsing back together, but not from being pulled apart (well, ok, there are small latches there that do that, but they're so small I doubt they're meant to be load bearing)

Maybe this link will work better https://www.wernerco.com/us/products/ladders/extension-ladders/B7100-2Series/B7116-2 It's a 16ft (fully extended) fiberglass ladder

Looks nice. Just two problems - one is that I haven't seen anything like that around here, although I certainly haven't checked all my options, so it's likely that someone does sell a product like that near me. But the second one is price - the one you linked goes for almost $500. That's waaay out of my budget right now. That's a fair price for a professional tool, but I'm going to use it once a year at best. Though maybe it can be rented somewhere... I'll check that out if I can't come up with anything else.

I linked to the higher commercial grade, but the one in my post goes to a lower grade half that price in the US. YMMV on pricing and availability
